# Semantic analyzer for checking type incompatibilities - Symbol table Implementation?

Tags: semantic-analysis

I got this code for Semanitic Analysis. Can't figure out the code for Symbol Table to make it run? Making a 2D array like this :

```
String[,] Symboltable = new String[20, 6];
```

Gives error of wrong number of indices inside, which I resolved but still wouldn't work. What is the other way I could do this?

## Region Semantic Analyzer

```
    void Semantic_Analysis(int k)
    {
        Regex variable_Reg = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z|_][A-Za-z|0-9]*$");
        if (finalArray[k].Equals("+"))
        {
            if (variable_Reg.Match(finalArray[k - 1] + "").Success && variable_Reg.Match(finalArray[k + 1] + "").Success)
            {
                String type = finalArray[k - 4] + "";
                String left_side = finalArray[k - 3] + "";
                int left_side_i = 0;
                int left_side_j = 0;
                String before = finalArray[k - 1] + "";
                int before_i = 0;
                int before_j = 0;
                String after = finalArray[k + 1] + "";
                int after_i = 0;
                int after_j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < Symboltable.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Symboltable[i].Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (Symboltable[i][j].Equals(left_side))
                        { left_side_i = i; left_side_j = j; }
                        if (Symboltable[i][j].Equals(before))
                        { before_i = i; before_j = j; }
                        if (Symboltable[i][j].Equals(after))
                        { after_i = i; after_j = j; }
                    }
                }
                if (type.Equals(Symboltable[before_i][2]) && type.Equals(Symboltable[after_i][2]) && Symboltable[before_i][2].Equals(Symboltable[after_i][2]))
                {
                    int Ans = Convert.ToInt32(Symboltable[before_i][3]) + Convert.ToInt32(Symboltable[after_i][3]);
                    Constants.Add(Ans);
                }
                if (Symboltable[left_side_i][2].Equals(Symboltable[before_i][2]) && Symboltable[left_side_i][2].Equals(Symboltable[after_i][2]) && Symboltable[before_i][2].Equals(Symboltable[after_i][2]))
                {
                    int Ans = Convert.ToInt32(Symboltable[before_i][3]) + Convert.ToInt32(Symboltable[after_i][3]);
                    Constants.RemoveAt(Constants.Count - 1);
                    Constants.Add(Ans);
                    Symboltable[left_side_i][3] = Ans + "";
                }
            }
        }
        if (finalArray[k].Equals("-"))
        {
            if (variable_Reg.Match(finalArray[k - 1] + "").Success && variable_Reg.Match(finalArray[k + 1] + "").Success)
            {
                String type = finalArray[k - 4] + "";
                String left_side = finalArray[k - 3] + "";
                int left_side_i = 0;
                int left_side_j = 0;
                String before = finalArray[k - 1] + "";
                int before_i = 0;
                int before_j = 0;
                String after = finalArray[k + 1] + "";
                int after_i = 0;
                int after_j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < Symboltable.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Symboltable[i].Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (Symboltable[i][j].Equals(left_side))
                        { left_side_i = i; left_side_j = j; }
                        if (Symboltable[i][j].Equals(before))
                        { before_i = i; before_j = j; }
                        if (Symboltable[i][j].Equals(after))
                        { after_i = i; after_j = j; }
                    }
                }
                if (type.Equals(Symboltable[before_i][2]) && type.Equals(Symboltable[after_i][2]) && Symboltable[before_i][2].Equals(Symboltable[after_i][2]))
                {
                    int Ans = Convert.ToInt32(Symboltable[before_i][3]) - Convert.ToInt32(Symboltable[after_i][3]);
                    Constants.Add(Ans);
                }
                if (Symboltable[left_side_i][2].Equals(Symboltable[before_i][2]) && Symboltable[left_side_i][2].Equals(Symboltable[after_i][2]) && Symboltable[before_i][2].Equals(Symboltable[after_i][2]))
                {
                    int Ans = Convert.ToInt32(Symboltable[before_i][3]) + Convert.ToInt32(Symboltable[after_i][3]);
                    Constants.RemoveAt(Constants.Count - 1);
                    Constants.Add(Ans);
                    Symboltable[left_side_i][3] = Ans + "";
                }
            }
        }
        if (finalArray[k].Equals(">"))
        {
            if (variable_Reg.Match(finalArray[k - 1] + "").Success && variable_Reg.Match(finalArray[k + 1] + "").Success)
            {
                String before = finalArray[k - 1] + "";
                int before_i = 0;
                int before_j = 0;
                String after = finalArray[k + 1] + "";
                int after_i = 0;
                int after_j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < Symboltable.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Symboltable[i].Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (Symboltable[i][j].Equals(before))
                        { before_i = i; before_j = j; }
                        if (Symboltable[i][j].Equals(after))
                        { after_i = i; after_j = j; }
                    }
                }
                if (Convert.ToInt32(Symboltable[before_i][3]) > Convert.ToInt32(Symboltable[after_i][3]))
                {
                    int start_of_else = finalArray.IndexOf("else");
                    int end_of_else = finalArray.Count - 1;
                    for (int i = end_of_else; i >= start_of_else; i--)
                    {
                        if (finalArray[i].Equals("}"))
                        {
                            if (i < finalArray.Count - 2)
                            { end_of_else = i; }
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = start_of_else; i <= end_of_else; i++)
                    { finalArray.RemoveAt(start_of_else); }
                }
                else
                {
                    int start_of_if = finalArray.IndexOf("if");
                    int end_of_if = finalArray.IndexOf("}");

                    for (int i = start_of_if; i <= end_of_if; i++)
                    { finalArray.RemoveAt(start_of_if); }
                    if_deleted = true;
                }

            }
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: 2D arrays in C# are indexed in a way that "look the same" as the type if you know what I mean, so `Symboltable[i, j]`

Comment: How do I resolve the issue of count, Symboltable.Count doesn't work on it.

Comment: `GetLength`, if you must. It's probably easier to convert the declaration and initialization to jagged, instead of all of this code.